# Basis for a polynomial vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

I am given the following here...

$V=\mathbb P_5$,

$W=\{p(x)\in \mathbb P_5|p(0)=p(1)=p(2)\}$

and I am asked to find a basis for $W$ and order it by increasing degree.

So my initial goal was to write a general 5th order polynomial as such:

$p(x)=a+bx+cx^2+dx^3+ex^4+fx^5$

Then, $p(0)=a$ and

$p(1)=a+b+c+d+e+f=a$

$0=b+c+d+e+f$.

If I solve for $b$, I get $b=-c-d-e-f$

So $p(x)=a-c(x+x^2)-d(x+x^3)-e(x+x^4)-f(x+x^4)$

Now the problem I am facing is that I can't write a as a linear combination of the other polynomials because I can't write a in terms of the other coefficients.

Did I completely go wrong or is there something I am missing?

Thanks...

Comment: You still have not used the fact that $p(2)=p(0)$

Comment: I tried to but that still ends up cancelling out a so I didn't think it would be very useful.

Comment: Perhaps try $p(2)=p(1)$ which will get you another equation.

Comment: Any polynomial can be written in the form $x(x-1)(x-2)q(x)+r(x)$ via long division.  The condition $p(0)=p(1)=p(2)$ and the degree of the polynomial as a whole will imply certain constraints on $q$ and $r$.

Comment: No matter how I write it though, the a cancels. Whether I use $p(2)=p(1)$ does not make any difference.

Comment: $p(2)=p(1)$ gives $b+c+7d+15e+31f=0$. Now, combining it with the equation you already found gives you a system of equations.

Comment: The set contains all constant polynomials so add $1$ to the basis. No linear ones as these are determined by 2 points, so if $p(0) = p(1)$ for a linear $p$, it must be constant. It does contain a third degree polynomail $p_3(x) = x(x-1)(x-2)$ Does it contain a quadratic one? Extend $\{1, p_3\}$  and the quadraic you might find to a basis,a s they're clearly independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on my comment above:

By [polynomial long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) and the fact that polynomial space is a euclidean space (*i.e. euclidean division algorithm works*) we know that **every** polynomial can be written **uniquely** as

$$f(x)=(x(x-1)(x-2))q(x)+r(x)$$

with $r(x)=0$ or the degree of $r(x)$ strictly less than three.

Ordinarily with no extra conditions, this implies that $\{x^2(x(x-1)(x-2)),~~ x(x(x-1)(x-2)),~~ (x(x-1)(x-2)),~~ x^2,~~ x,~~ 1\}$ forms a basis for $\Bbb P_5$

That is to say, any degree five or less polynomial can be written uniquely in the form $$f(x)=x(x-1)(x-2)(ax^2+bx+c)+dx^2+ex+f$$

The condition that $f(0)=f(1)=f(2)$ implies that with $f(x)=(x(x-1)(x-2))q(x)+r(x)$ that $r(x)$ must be a constant, implying $d=e=0$

One such choice of a basis is then $\{x^2(x(x-1)(x-2)),~~ x(x(x-1)(x-2)),~~ (x(x-1)(x-2)),~~ 1\}$

Rewritten if you prefer:

$$\{x^5-3x^4+2x^3,~~x^4-3x^3+2x^2,~~ x^3-3x^2+2x,~~1\}$$

Comment: I get the last part but I am just wondering how that basis was initially obtained. I mean, I can see how the degrees of P are increasing by the remainder theorem. I used it in a previous question as a larger part of the problem but I am just having trouble figuring out how I can write the polynomial as a linearly independent set. Sorry about this. My linear algebra is fairly rusty.

Comment: @SubhashisChakraborty Since $p(x)=(x^3-3x^2+2x)q(x)+r(x)$ is uniquely determined by $q(x)$ and $r(x)$, by ranging over all possibilities of what $q(x)$ and what $r(x)$ are we get all possible fifth or less degree polynomials.  Letting $q(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and $r(x)=dx^2+ex+f$ we see that the choices of $a,b,c,d,e,f$ uniquely determine the polynomial $p(x)$.  By setting a single one of the free variables equal to one and all of the remaining equal to zero and ranging over all choices of which free variable was the one equal to one, we get ourselves the basis of $\Bbb P_5$.

Comment: We know $q(x)$ must be at most degree two since otherwise $p(x)$ could be higher than degree five and we know $r(x)$ must be at most degree two as per the euclidean division algorithm.

Comment: We chose to do this so that we could specifically isolate how $p(0),p(1)$ and $p(2)$ relate to one another.  Since plugging in $0,1$ or $2$ will make $x^3-3x^2+2x=0$, the entire left side of the expression will cancel out and we simply get $p(0)=r(0), p(1)=r(1), p(2)=r(2)$

Comment: Yes I got it now. I did it a little differently but it makes perfect sense. Thanks so much!